# Ffmpeg - Exclamation Point Stopping Watermark

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, watermark, ffprobe

I am using the code below to automatically watermark videos in a folder:

```
for %%a in ("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Redo\*.mp4") do (
   for /F "delims=" %%I in ('ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream^=width -of csv^=p^=0:s^=x %%a') do set "codec=%%I"
   ffmpeg -i logo.png -y -v quiet -vf scale=!codec!*0.25:-1 scaled.png
   ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "movie=scaled.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h [out]" "C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Redo Done\%%~na.mp4"
)
```

Some of the videos fail to watermark and give the similar error below:

```
C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Redo\Arcade_h-overlay_h [out]: No such file or directory
```

I found out all videos with exclamation points **(!)** in the name do this.

How can I get these videos to watermark with an exclamation point in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cmd
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ("C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Redo\*.mp4") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
        ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream^=width -of csv^=p^=0:s^=x "%%a"
    ') do (
        ffmpeg -i logo.png -y -v quiet -vf scale=%%I*0.25:-1 scaled.png
        ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "movie=scaled.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h [out]" "C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Redo Done\%%~na.mp4"
    )
)
```

Exclamation points will be lost when expanding the `for` replaceable parameters when delayed expansion is active. As you are only using delayed expansion to retrieve the `codec` value, don't do it, you don't need it. The value inside the variable is already available as a `for` replaceable parameter, so, simply place the `ffmpeg` commands inside the second `for` and directly use the retrieved value.